# Minor issue about the proof of the Cauchy Convergence Criterion on Understanding Analysis (Abbott)

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation

I don't understand one small part of the proof of the following statement:

> If a sequence is a Cauchy sequence, then it converges.

**PROOF:**

Let $(x_n)$ be a a Cauchy sequence. Then it is bounded (by another lemma) and Balzano-Weierstrass theorem guarantees that there is a convergent subsequence $x_{n_j}$ such that $x=\lim x_{n_j}$. Let $\varepsilon>0$. Since $x_n$ is Cauchy, there exists an $N$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<\varepsilon/2$ whenever $m,n \geq N$.

Since, $(x_{n_j}) \to x$, we can choose a term $x_{n_k}$ in this subsequence such that $n_k\geq N$. It follows that $|x_{n_k}-x|<\varepsilon/2$. If $n \geq n_k$, then

$$|x_n-x| \leq |x_n-x_{n_k}|+|x_{n_k}-x| < \varepsilon/2+\varepsilon/2=\varepsilon \;\;\square$$

**Question:**

I don't understand why $n \geq n_k$ is needed in the last line. As far as I understand, we are replacing subscript $m$ with $n_k$ both greater or equal than $N$. So isn't $n \geq N$ sufficient enough for the triangle inequality? What happens if $n \leq n_k$?

Comment: What guarantees that $|x_{n_k}-x| < \epsilon/2$ for all $n_k \geq N$? The $N$ was found by applying the Cauchy condition which is unrelated to the subsequence. What we do know is that since $x_{n_k}$ converges there exist a $M$ such that if $n_k\geq M$ then $|x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon/2$.

Comment: @Winther Instead of $n \geq n_k$ can I use $n \geq max(N,M)$ then? Because I still can't see the point of the $n \geq n_k$.

Comment: It should be $n\ge N$. Also, you choose $n_k$ such that $|x_{n_k}-x|<\frac\epsilon2$, where you can assume that $n_k\ge N$.

Comment: I am really confused with the contradicting replies.

Answer (score 0):

The first $N$ we get comes from the fact that the sequence is Cauchy. We also need some other $m$ to guarantee that the terms $x_{n_k}$ for $k\ge m$ are within $\epsilon/2$ of the limit. The proof is fine as written, but I would have phrased it in the following way.

Since $x_{n_k}\to x$ as $n_k\to\infty$, there is some $m\in\Bbb N$ such that
$|x_{n_k} - x| < \epsilon/2$ whenenver $n_k\ge n_m$. Thus if $M = \max(N,n_m)$, then whenever $n\ge M$, we have
$$
|x_n - x| \le |x_{n_m}-x| + |x_{n_m}-x_n| < \epsilon/2 + \epsilon/2 = \epsilon,
$$
as desired.